# how I can implements multiFilter with datatype list in ML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

```
datatype 'a Multilist = 
   Node of 'a list
 | List of 'a Multilist list;

fun isGreaterThen x y = y > x;

fun multiFilter  f (List([])) = []  
  | multiFilter  f  (List(m::multil)) = 
    let fun flattenAuxiliray(Node(value)) = 
                   if (f value = true) then (value) else nil
          | flattenAuxiliray((List(nil))) = nil
          | flattenAuxiliray(List(m::mlist1)) = (flattenAuxiliray(m)) @ 
                   (flattenAuxiliray((List(mlist1)))) 
    in (flattenAuxiliray(m)) @ (multiFilter f (List(multil)))
    end;
```

I get error on this input:

```
val l = List [Node [3,5,18], Node [7]];
multiFilter (isGreaterThen 6) l;

stdIn:7.1-8.46 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: ('Z list -> bool) * 'Z list Multilist
  operand:         (int -> bool) * int list Multilist
  in expression:
    multiFilter (isGreaterThen 6,List (Node <exp> :: <exp> :: <exp>))
```

output:

```
val it = [18,7] : int list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type error is saying that the first parameter is expecting something of type `'Z list -> bool`, meaning it is a function that takes in a polymorphic list and returns a bool.  However, you are supplying a function that takes an `int` and returns a bool.  It instead should take in a list of `int`s and return a `bool`.  You can achieve this by changing `isGreaterThan` (of type `int -> int -> bool`) to something of type `int -> int list -> bool`, which will compare everything in the list to the first parameter, returning true only when all elements are smaller.

Comment: I can't change isGreaterThan and datatype

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has its root here:

```
flattenAuxiliray(Node(value)) = 
                   if (f value = true) then (value) else nil
```

Your data type says `Node of 'a list` so `value` must be an `'a list`.
Since you apply `f` to `value`, `f` must have the type `'a list -> bool`, but you're passing `isGreaterThan 6`, which has type `int -> bool`.

You're probably looking for a `filter` in order to remove all the elements that don't satisfy the predicate:

```
flattenAuxiliray (Node value) = 
                   List.filter f value
```

(Side note: an abundance of parentheses and lack of whitespace makes SML very hard to read. Remember that code spends most of its time neither written or executed, but read by humans.)

Complete function:

```
fun multiFilter  f (List []) = []  
  | multiFilter  f (List (m::multil)) = 
    let fun flattenAuxiliary (Node ls) = List.filter f ls
          | flattenAuxiliary (List []) = []
          | flattenAuxiliary (List (m::mlist1))
            = (flattenAuxiliary m) @ (flattenAuxiliary (List mlist1)) 
    in (flattenAuxiliary m) @ (multiFilter f (List multil))
    end;
```

Interaction:

```
- multiFilter (isGreaterThan 6) (List [Node [3,5,18],Node [7]]);
val it = [18,7] : int list
```

Comment: I need to pass on list only one time.

Comment: @alex I don't understand.

Comment: I can iterate over a list only one time.  My initiate list is List [Node [3,5,18], Node [7]]

Comment: You will only traverse the multi list once — in order to traverse it fully you need to also traverse the "standard" lists it contains, and the `List.filter` does that. I updated with the complete function.